# TypeError: object is not a function - github passport setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to setup an oauth strategy for github using passport. This same setup works for setting up a twitter strategy. Think I'm making a simple javascript error, but not sure where.

```
var  passport = require('passport'),
     GithubStrategy = require('passport-github'),
     config = require('./config/oauth.js');

passport.use(new GithubStrategy({
    clientID: config.github.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.github.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.github.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            return done(null, profile);
        });
    }
));
```

Here's the error stack I get;

```
passport.use(new GithubStrategy({
         ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kevin/gd/proj/priv/Vebulid/app.js:42:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kevin/gd/proj/priv/Vebulid/bin/www:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.Strategy` property:

```
var GithubStrategy = require('passport-github').Strategy;
```